# Magento 1.9 Impossible to log in on backend, said to be because of hosting space limitations. Is this true?

Tags: magento-1.9, log, admin-login

Magento 1.9  Impossible to log in on backend, said to be because of hosting space limitations. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, If your server dosen't have more space & your session are stored in file system then it would be true.

Comment: Ok, now how could I resolve this problem without increasing my hosting space?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the session files and try to login. If it does, the server is overloaded with session files, and Magento cannot create more for a new session.

Comment: Thanks.....how to remove the session files?

Answer (score 0):

Try clear/delete the Files by login into your hosting panel. check in the /var/log/ path.